# Show menu after 2 seconds

Tags: jquery, html, delay, show

Im trying having problems on showing a `<div>` after 2 seconds..
My problem is that when i hover the button, the menu is displayed with no delay, and i want a delay of 2 secs...

Try to hover: Mere på cabiweb, then the menu will display -> You can see it [here](http://cabiweb.inforce.dk)

The code :

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#dropdown").hover(function(){
        $(".drop-inner").delay(2000).show();
      });
    });</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a timeout rather than `.delay()`, the latter only [affects queued functions](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) (such as effects):

```
$("#dropdown").hover(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".drop-inner").show();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascripts `setTimeout` function to delay execution:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#dropdown").hover(function() {

       setTimeout(function() {
          $(".drop-inner").show()
       }, 2000);

     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Nicky - you are missing the closing `);` from the hover function on your website.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like `.show()` will work with `.delay()`:

> Added to jQuery in version 1.4, the .delay() method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the `setTimeout` solution, but ... what if the user moves away mouse cursor from the `#dropdown` before those 2 seconds elapses?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#dropdown").hover(function(){
            $.data(this, "timer", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
                $(".drop-inner").show();
            }, this), 2000));
        },
        function() {
            clearTimeout($.data(this, "timer"));
            $(".drop-inner").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Check the example on http://jsfiddle.net/vundicind/Lqq3h1xa/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout(expression, delay);`

```
$("#dropdown").hover(function(){
    setTimeout(doSomething(), 2000);
  });
});
```

And then in a separate function

```
<script>
    function doSomething() {
        $(".drop-inner").show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work :( i've triede setting it to ex: 20 secs, but still appearing right away on hover

Comment: @Nicky Christensen Is the doSomething function outside the `$(document).ready(function { });`?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the jQuery docs:

> The `.delay()` method is best for
>   delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it
>   doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay. `.delay()` is not a
>   replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more
>   appropriate for certain use cases.

If you were using `fadeIn` or some other jQuery effect, your code would have worked between effects.

What you want to do is something like http://jsfiddle.net/BQhwd/

I assumed you wanted a `hide()` after 2 seconds as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try this function [Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#dropdown").hover(function(){
        $(".drop-inner").animate({},2000,function(){
         //animation complete
});

      });
    });</script>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. .animate is for animations and not for timing control.